# NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing

Tags: node.js, npm, version, zeromq, failed-installation

I am trying to execute a node app which was provided to me and it is supposed to work fine.

I have tried running it but I am not able to fix this error:

```
seba@vps92941:~/services/drivetech$ node awto.js
/home/seba/services/drivetech/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
        ^

Error: The module '/home/seba/services/drivetech/node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:731:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at bindings (/home/seba/services/drivetech/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/seba/services/drivetech/node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:6:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
```

---

### I have already tried :

- Re-building the module (zmq)
- Removing and re-installing the module
- Uninstall everything (node included), install again
- Re-building zmq as global module

How can I get rid of this? I don't know what else to do.

These are my node & npm versions:

**node: v10.4.0

npm: 3.5.2**

Comment: Check `nodejs --version`. I had a similar problem caused by a difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177520/how-can-i-install-node-module-version-46/56187259#56187259).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem with bcrypt moving from node 8 to node 10 and finally I solved by manually invoking node-pre-gyp:

```
cd node_modules/<module_name>
node-pre-gyp rebuild
```

This forced the node-pre-gyp tool (the tool used by node to compila binary modules) to take the correct version of node.

Maybe reinstall it before executing to be sure that you have the correct version of node-pre-gyp

```
npm i -g node-pre-gyp
```

Hope this helps