# How can I install NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46

Tags: npm, installation, version

How can I install a Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46? I keep running into a NODE_MODULE_VERSION mismatch, and recompiling hasn't helped so switching node versions might be easier.

Basically, I keep coming across this:

```
Warning: The module '/home/cwaugh/workspaces/myproject/build/Release/addon.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`). Use --force to continue.
```

So far, I've tried using `n` to change to different versions (one of my dependencies requires 4.9.1 or below), but that doesn't seem to change the NODE_MODULE_VERSION as recognized by the warning.

I've also tried recompiling:

- I've tried deleting node_modules and running `npm install` again. (this error looks like it's coming from the project root, but it never worked for anything in the node_modules folder either)
- `node-gyp configure --target=4.9.1 && node-gyp build --target=4.9.1`. I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565777/node-gyp-compiling-against-wrong-node-module-version), and hoped I'd have better luck than mxcd.
- `node-pre-gyp rebuild`. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805005/node-module-version-46-this-version-of-node-js-requires-node-module-version-64), and thought it might work for me.

This works on another, older computer running a vagrant image. Unfortunately, vagrant isn't working on the new computer either, so I've been trying from scratch. Sometimes, I wonder if it's because I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The server's can't seem to go past 16.04 when they run our docker image.

Comment: I GOT IT TO CHANGE. When I upgraded my version of nan, I was able to use npm 6.17.1, which changed the message to `compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULES_ 48`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I GOT IT!

It turns out I was getting different versions from node and nodejs

```
$ node --version
v4.9.1
$ nodejs --version
v8.10.0
```

I upgrade to node v8.10.0, redo everything, and the error's gone!

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 8.10.0
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
node-gyp clean
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
grunt build
grunt start
# No more NODE_MODULE_VERSION error
```

I tried uninstalling nodejs (since this it's been replaced by just "node"), but node-grunt-cli requires it. I'm guessing that grunt uses nodejs instead of node to check its version, causing the error. The Ubuntu repositories have Grunt v0.4.5, while Grunt stable is at v1.0.3, so it's possible a newer version of grunt would also solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution didn't work for me since I had just one node version (10).
What was happening in my project, was that the `package.json` was pulled from the remote repository with an old version package.

At the moment of installing node modules locally (using **yarn**), it would download up-to-date dependencies, creating incompatibility.

After trying several solutions, what finally worked for me was picking the specific package that was giving me headache (`login-funcs-nodejs`) and run:`yarn upgrade login-funcs-nodejs --latest`